# Where can I get all supported formats of AUTOCAD?

Tags: autocad, autodesk

Where can I get all supported formats of AUTOCAD?

Here is a [list](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/) of all supported AUTOCAD formats are mentioned in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The list you posted is for translation webservice, not for AutoCAD (desktop application).

AutoCAD supports read/write from .DWG (primary) but also work with .DXF (text file). It can import and export a series of formats, but on specific workflows. For instance, you can export as .DWF (read-only output, like a PDF).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to research your question? I search for **AutoCAD Export** and it came up with this web page [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-A72DB257-3410-4792-B548-6B9FC1DED72B-htm.html).

[image: Export Formats]